# How to set image size is dynamically in poi word run.addPicture()?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

```java
XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();
InputStream a = someMethod(underConditions(inputimage));
paragraph.createRun().addPicture(a, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "", Units.toEMU(20), Units.toEMU(20));
a.close();
doc.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooter.docx"));
doc.close();
```

This is simple code for add a image in poi word. But InputStream a is different under different conditions. If `inputimage` is small `Units.toEMU(20), Units.toEMU(20)` is to big, and if `inputimage` is big `Units.toEMU(20), Units.toEMU(20)` is too small. In this conditions images are distorted.

So my question is: how to set dynamic image size based on different image?

Comment: "set dynamic image size based on different image" Based on what exactly? Inserting the image in its preferred size dependent on the image file always? - This can lead to very big images sometimes. Or having width or height as fixed size and scaling the other dimension dependent on the original images ratio?

Comment: yes, insert image has its own suitable size, I want to set width and height based on image's suitable size, not set fixed size like Units.toEMU(20), Units.toEMU(20). Is this feasible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we need determining the preferred dimensions of the images from their files. There are already much discussions on how to do that. Search keywords: `java get dimension from image file`.  Simplest possibility is using `ImageIO` to read `BufferedImage` from the file which then has `width`and `height` properties.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CreateWordImagesPreferredSize {

 static Dimension getImageDimension(File imgFile) throws IOException {
  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
  return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Images:");

  String[] images = new String[]{"Koala.png", "Scannen.jpg", "Winter.bmp"};

  for (int i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++) {

   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun();
  
   File imgFile = new File(images[i]);
   Dimension dim = getImageDimension(imgFile);
   System.out.println(dim);

   double width = dim.getWidth();
   double height = dim.getHeight();

   double scaling = 1.0;
   if (width > 72*6) scaling = (72*6)/width; //scale width not to be greater than 6 inches

   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
   paragraph.createRun().addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, images[i], 
    Units.toEMU(width*scaling), Units.toEMU(height*scaling));
   in.close();

  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordImagesPreferredSize.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();        
 }
}
```

Note: I do scaling the image to be not greater than 6 inches width if its original size is greater. So it will fit into one page width. Smaller images will not be scaled.

---

Edit:

As from the comments, if you cannot using `File` but must using `InputStream`, then you need to know, that `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgStream);` of course reads from the stream. So the stream will be at its end after that. So `.addPicture(imgStream,...)` will need a newly opened stream then.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CreateWordImagesPreferredSizeStream {

 static InputStream getInputStream(String filename) throws Exception {
  return new FileInputStream(filename);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Images:");

  String[] images = new String[]{"Koala.png", "Scannen.jpg", "Winter.bmp"};

  for (int i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++) {

   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun();

   InputStream imgStream = getInputStream(images[i]);

   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgStream);
   double w = img.getWidth();
   double h = img.getHeight();
   imgStream.close();

   System.out.println(w);
   System.out.println(h);

   double scaling = 1.0;
   if (w > 72*6) scaling = (72*6)/w; //scale width not to be greater than 6 inches

   imgStream = getInputStream(images[i]);

   paragraph.createRun().addPicture(imgStream, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, images[i], 
    Units.toEMU(w*scaling), Units.toEMU(h*scaling));
   imgStream.close();

  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordImagesPreferredSize.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();    
 }
}
```

Comment: `InputStream imgStream = getImgStreamMethod(), BufferedImage img= ImageIO.read(imgStream), int w = img.getWidth(), int h = img.getHeight(), paragraph.createRun().addPicture(imgStream, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,"",Units.toEMU(w*scale),Units.toEMU(h*scale))` If  I add this related ImageIO code, in my word file, my image cannot be display, and there is a error in my image location says: The image cannot not be display.Your computer may not be have enough memory to open the image, or the image may have been corrupted. Restart you computer......... If I remove ImageIO code, image can display.

Comment: I generate image in some method, so there is no imageFile here. I want to imageIO.reade(imgStream) here, then get the width and height. Why this error appear? Thanks!

Comment: Thats pretty clear. `BufferedImage img= ImageIO.read(imgStream)` reads from the stream. So after that, the stream will be at its end. So `.addPicture(imgStream, ...)` needs a newly opened stream then. But what kind of stream is it? Using a `FileInputStream` will often not lead to valuablee results in `ImageIO` as of my experience. Please provide **all** necessary informations. But not in a comment but in your **question** please.

Comment: See my supplement.