# How to add a picture to .docx with Apache POI XWPF without specifying its size

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I'm using Apache POI XWPF to insert an image into .docx file with the following code:

```java
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFRun run = docx.addParagraph().createRun();
run.addPicture(<input_stream>, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "filename", Units.toEMU(250), Units.toEMU(140));
```

Problem is that it is required to specify both height and width of the image, which I may not know.

I want to add an image without providing its dimensions or only providing one of them (so another one will be calculated to keep images aspect ratio).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511968/how-to-set-image-size-is-dynamically-in-poi-word-run-addpicture/43514492#43514492

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you. I know it is possible to process an image before to get its dimensions. I wanted to know whether it is possible to achieve the same without analyzing an image.